# How to play a video inside mobile safari

Tags: iphone, ios, video, safari, mobile-safari

I'm using a simple HTML5 video tag to reproduce an mp4 video in the iphone browser but it always open the video player on the iphone.

Is there a way to play the video inside the browser?

```
<video src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4"
        autoplay="autoplay" <!-- Boolean attribute. Omit to prevent autoplay. -->
        start="00:00:00.00"
        loopstart="00:00:00.07" <!-- 7 seconds -->
        loopend="00:00:00.19"
        end="00:00:00.27"
        playcount="4" <!-- play 4x -->
        controls="true"
        width="640"
        height="480"
>
```

This is my code I'm using, and works well in a normal browser but in the iphone it allways opens in the video player.

Thanks!

Comment: Yea, I guarantee to you that it works, but we need to see what you're doing wrong to help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, iPhones always open HTML5 video in the native player (to avoid postage-stamp sized videos). iPads will play it within Safari using the same code. I don't believe there's a way to override this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `playsinline`
    `<video … playsinline />`